# Visual C++ Library for converting set of images to a video without using Opencv

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gdal

I am working on a project in Visual C++. I have a 10 to 20 images (.jpeg) in my directory and I wanted to convert that into a video of any format (.avi/.mp4) in which those images are shown after specified interval. I am using Visual C++ (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010). Please someone help me. If someone could provide the source code, that would be really helpful. I don't want to use Opencv. Please suggest some other available libraries along with some information about it. (In short, any alternative library for OpenCv?)

Comment: it does not need an opencv tag in this case ;)

Comment: @berak: I thought Opencv experts might know the answer ;)

Comment: @RawN: My question is to convert 10 to 20 images to a video without using Opencv. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using **DirectShow**. Take a look at the following sample:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377481(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide some source code reference? That would be really helpful.

Comment: To download the DirectShow SDK samples, install the latest version of the Windows SDK.